# Updating an object property within an array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am on the newer side of React and trying to change the state of an object in an array. Currently, I am pulling the object out of the array, changing the property in that object, then adding the new object to the state again. Problem being that it sends the object to the back of the list and reorders my checkbox inputs.

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {

    if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {

      // Get the role from the current state
      const roleToChange = input.roles.find(
        (role) => Number(role.id) === Number(e.target.id)
      );

      // Change checked state to opposite of current state
      const changedRole = { ...roleToChange, checked: !roleToChange.checked };

      // Get every role except the one that was changed
      const newRoles = input.roles.filter(
        (role) => Number(role.id) !== Number(e.target.id)
      );

      // Update the role in the state
      setInput((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, roles: [...newRoles, changedRole] };
      });
    }
```

Can I update the object in the array in-place so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `.filter` - `.map` instead, and return the changed object in case the ID matches, so the new object gets put at the same place in the new array as it was originally.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.type !== "checkbox") {
        return;
    };

    const newRoles = input.roles.map((role) =>
        Number(role.id) !== Number(e.target.id)
          ? role
          : { ...role, checked: !role.checked }
    );

    setInput((prevState) => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            roles: newRoles
        };
    });
}
```

Unless the state is updated synchronously before this, which sounds a bit unlikely (but not impossible), you can also probably use `setInput({ ...input, roles: newRules })` instead of the callback.

Comment: Two questions/comments: 1.) is there a reason you chose to `return` when `!== "checkbox"` instead of the way I had it? 2.) I saw in a course that `setInput({ ...input, roles: newRules })` causes errors and you should *always* pass the `prevState` as a callback - is this outdated or too simple of a thought?

Comment: (1) Just a style choice. Returning immediately cuts down on indentation. If you use lots of `if() { if () { if () {` it quickly becomes difficult to determine at a glance what logical block you're in, and what `}` matches to what `{` 30+ lines above.

Comment: (2) That recommendation is definitely wrong. While there are certainly cases where you need to use the callback form for the logic to work properly, those cases are in the distinct minority. Passing the new state value instead of using a callback works in most cases and is shorter (and therefore easier to understand at a glance, which is the most important thing to strive for in programming IMO). Use the callback form when you need to, but you probably don't want use it everywhere just because the syntax is technically permitted.